# RData takes longer to load than querying the database again

Tags: sql-server, r, rstudio-server, rdata

I am running RStudio Server on a 256GB RAM server, and MS-SQL-Server 2012 on another. This DB contains data that allows me to build a graph with ~100 million nodes and ~150 million edges.

I have timed how long it takes to build this graph from that data:

- 1st SELECT query = ˜22M rows = 12 minutes = df1 (dataframe1)
- 2nd SELECT query = ˜30M rows = 8 minutes = df2
- 3rd SELECT query = ˜32M rows = 8 minutes = df3
- 4th SELECT query = ˜63M rows = 70 minutes = df4
- `edges = rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)` = 6 minutes
- `mygraph = graph.data.frame(edges)` = 30 minutes

So a little over two hours. Since my data is quite stable, I figured I could speed things up by saving `mygraph` to disk. But when I tried to load it, it just wouldn't. I gave up after a 4 hour wait, thinking something had gone wrong.

So I reboot the server, delete my .rstudio folder and start over, this time saving the dataframes from each SQL query plus the `edges` dataframe, in both RData and RDS formats (`save()` and `saveRDS()`, `compress = FALSE` everytime). After each save, I timed `load()` and `readRDS()` times of the five dataframes. Times where pretty much the same for `load()` and `readRDS()`:

- df1 = 1.1 GB file = 1 minute
- df2 = 1.4 GB file = 2 minutes
- df3 = 1.7 GB file = 6 minutes
- df4 = 3.1 GB file = 13 minutes
- edges = 6.8 GB file = 21 minutes

Good enough, I thought. But today when I started a new session and tried to `load(df1)` to make some changes to it, again I got that feeling that something was wrong. After 20 minutes waiting for it to load, I gave up. Memory, disk and CPU shouldn't be the issues, as I'm the only one using this server. I have already reboot the server and deleted my .rstudio folder, thinking maybe something in there was hanging my session, but the dataframe still won't load. While `load()` is supposedly running, `iotop` shows no disk activity and this is what I get from `ps`

`ps -C rsession -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
%CPU %MEM CMD
99.5  0.3 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession -u myusername`

I have no idea what to try next. It makes no sense to me that loading a RData file would take longer than querying a SQL database that lives on a different server. And even if it did, then why was it so fast when I was timing `load()` and `readRDS()` times after saving the dataframes?

It's the first time I ask something here at StackOverflow, so sorry if I forgot to mention something important for you to be able to answer this question. If I did, please let me know.

---

**EDIT:** some additional info requested by Brandon in the comments. OS is CentOS 7. The dataframes contain lists of edges in the first two columns (col1=node1; col2=node2) and two additional columns for edge attributes. All columns are strings, varying between 5 and 14 characters long. I have also added the approximate number of rows of each dataframe to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm jealous of your RAM.

Comment: I just tried saveRDS()/readRDS() and got 1.2 min save/ 12.5 second load with a 1.6gb data.frame on my Surface Pro 3 (a laptop). Something is amiss here. Can you tell us more about your data? Sparse? Dimensions? Operating system?